# Is my SG too low?

Tags: specific-gravity, original-gravity

I have an SG of 1,040, and the target OG is about 1.065. 
I was wondering if this is too low? 
Should I add more water?

Answer (score 2):

If this was a partial boil batch and you added water to top up after the boil, the problem is that you didn't get it mixed well enough before taking a reading.  It's a very common problem.  The wort, containing sugar, is heavier than water and sinks to the bottom of the fermener.  It's very difficult to get them thoroughly mixed, so the reading you get is from the watered down top portion.

Answer (score 1):

No, water would bring the SG closer to 1.0, which is the SG of water.